# Image preporcessing tehcnique to remove noise similar to the signal using Python?

Tags: image-processing, counting

I am trying to remove noise from my time-lapse images to count colonies on an agar plate, but the plate itself has noise that is similar to the colonies. So when I find the contours in the image it also picks up the noise from it.

[This what the Image looks like after subtracting the first frame of the time-lapse from it and converting to grayscale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or1Om.png)

I have tried using filtering methods like Gaussian and Median filtering. Also, tried using morphological operations like opening and top-hat filtering which did not work. Can you please suggest another exisiting way to get rid of this noise in python?

Comment: unfiltered source data please.

Comment: Hi, this is the link to the original images taken, the image shown previously was cropped from the third track from the left. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OtEHENASx4Q0eTx6RAIXa1AVEGR4U33K?usp=sharing

Comment: the entire environment is lit *fairly* consistently but the picture is moving a little (camera? the dish?). -- to compensate for the movement, try ECC refinement, in OpenCV. -- you could try a "background subtractor", available in OpenCV. you'd need to dial the learning rate way down, after warming it up on the first couple of frames. LR affects what changes are tolerated and what changes are marked as interesting. it can't be 0 because the background does change appearance a little and you do want it to adapt to that.

Comment: I see, yes there was movement in the images because of the camera's movement. So the workflow would be to first compensate for that movement and then subtract the background using something like the cv::BackgroundSubtractor class? Currently, I am using the first frame as a reference and subtracting it from all the images but the slight movement in the images could result in the noise I am seeing.